# Warnings in build.gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I created a Gradle project (for Jenkins Shared Library Development) in IntelliJ Idea 2020.2: I followed the tutorial on http://tdongsi.github.io/blog/2018/02/09/intellij-setup-for-jenkins-shared-library-development/. Here is the my build.gradle file (It comes from the tutorial, but I adpated to a recent version of Gradle):

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'org.jenkins.devopssec'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/' }
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['vars', 'src']
        }
    }

    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.connectbot.jbcrypt', name: 'jbcrypt', version: '1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.6'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.85'

    // Jenkins plugins
    implementation group: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins', name: 'credentials', version: '2.1.16', ext: 'jar'
    implementation group: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins', name: 'credentials-binding', version: '1.23', ext: 'jar'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.maven', name: 'maven-model', version: '3.6.3'

    testImplementation group: 'com.lesfurets', name: 'jenkins-pipeline-unit', version: '1.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

After refreshing the Gradle dependencies, I got the following warning that point in the lines `srcDirs = [...]` (in main and test source sets): cannot instantiate interface 'SourceSet'. The Inspection Description shows: assignment with incompatible types.

I looked in the internet for example of sourceSets, the majority uses the same ways of initializing the `srcDirs`. Has somebody came across this issue ?

By the way, the version of Gradle is 6.3 and I am using the OpenJDK 1.8.0_265 (on Linux Fedora 32).

Any suggestion or comment is welcome.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Reported here: [IDEA-253793](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253793).

Comment: That bug seems to be either deleted or private. When I click the link, YouTrack says "Nope, can't find it".

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to only appear in the situation when we use the "groovy" plugin. I tried to use the "java" plugin and no warning appeared.

Fortunately, it does not appear to have any effect on Gradle; the gradle build is normal, and all commands are normal. So I think it is an IDEA bug.

Because it had no effect on me, I ignored it when I used the Groovy plugin.

By the way, I used IntelliJ Idea 2021.3.